# changing textView in a seprate broadcastReceiver file

Tags: android

how should change the TextView which is in MainActivity ??
when i have the Receiver part in MainActivity file, it gives me App has stopped.
and when i separate them in two file, i can't change the TextView.
i used the code below(i dont' know it's correct or not just wanted to try different way but again didn't work)

```
Login textViewUpdater = new Login();
    textViewUpdater.updateTextView("network state changed",txtState);
```

these are what i've written:

```
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

public  TextView txtState;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        updateTextView("network is available",txtState);
    } else {
        updateTextView("no network",txtState);
    }
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable()
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo[] info = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void updateTextView (String text,TextView txtState)
{
    txtState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    txtState.setText(text);
}
}
```

and Receiver file:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CheckInternet extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public TextView txtState;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Login textViewUpdater = new Login();
        textViewUpdater.updateTextView("network state changed",txtState);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet state changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: You must ensure that any UI updates (such as setting text on a TextView) are done on the main thread.  Just put your textview update code in a Runnable and call runOnUiThread from your Activity.

Comment: BTW, instantiating an Activity like you are doing seems problematic.  You should leave it up to the Android framework to create your Activity through the normal means of either specifying it with a LAUNCHER intent filter in the manifest, or using an Intent to launch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referencing the text view correctly and are not on the UI thread.  Try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public TextView vConnectionStateTextView;
    private IntentFilter mConnectionChangeIntentFilter;
    private CheckConnectionReceiver mCheckConnectionReceiver = new CheckConnectionReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        updateConnectionText();
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo[] info = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mConnectionChangeIntentFilter == null) {
            mConnectionChangeIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        }

        registerReceiver(mCheckConnectionReceiver, mConnectionChangeIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mCheckConnectionReceiver);
    }

    public class CheckConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateConnectionText();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet state changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void updateConnectionText() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            vConnectionStateTextView.setText("network is available");
        } else {
            vConnectionStateTextView.setText("no network");
        }
    }
}
```